# Problems plotting exponential formula

Tags: r, plot, exponential

I am trying to make an exponential plot of a variable. The coefficient of the variable is very high (350 million) from the GLM results. With other variables that had lower coefficients, I was able to plot them easily with no issues. I have been trying to set the sequence interval smaller and smaller but it keeps crashing r when I try to plot it.
Any suggestions? I have tried breaking up the data already with no luck.
My vectors are very large numerics as well (18Mb).

```
chlautcnod<-seq.int(0, 2.45259, 0.000001)

chlautcnodline<- glmnodosaALL$coefficients[1] + 
glmnodosaALL$coefficients[2]*mean(bornodosaAP$Chl_spring) + 
glmnodosaALL$coefficients[3]*chlautcnod + glmnodosaALL$coefficients[4]*mean(bornodosaAP$Dist_coast) +
glmnodosaALL$coefficients[5]*mean(bornodosaAP$Chl_winter)+ glmnodosaALL$coefficients[6]*mean(bornodosaAP$Depth) +
glmnodosaALL$coefficients[7]*mean(bornodosaAP$Chl_yr_avg)+ glmnodosaALL$coefficients[8]*mean(bornodosaAP$Dist_complete_river) +
glmnodosaALL$coefficients[9]*mean(bornodosaAP$Temp_yr_min)+ glmnodosaALL$coefficients[10]*mean(bornodosaAP$Chl_summer)+
glmnodosaALL$coefficients[11]*mean(bornodosaAP$Chl_yr_max)+ glmnodosaALL$coefficients[12]*mean(bornodosaAP$SWH_summer)+
glmnodosaALL$coefficients[13]*mean(bornodosaAP$SWH_yr_min)+ glmnodosaALL$coefficients[14]*mean(bornodosaAP$SWH_spring)

gc(plot(exp(1)^chlautcnodline~chlautcnod, xlab = (expression(paste("Chlorophyll-α Autumn (mg/m"^"3"~")"))), ylab= "Probability of C. nodosa occurance",ylim=c(0,0.05),xlim=c(0.15,0.17), type="l", bty="l")
```

[image: 1]

Comment: How can I supply a reproducible example

Comment: Yes, attempting to send 2+ million x-y pairs to the plot function does sound like a recipe for disaster. Without being able to reproduce the issue, It is unlikely anyone will be able to provide any useful assistance.

Comment: Your definition for "chlautcnodline" looks like it is equal to glmnodosaALL$coefficients[3]*chlautcnod + (a bunch of constants).  Simplify this equation and provide information and the value for coefficients[3].